# How to save data in factory in angularjs after getting response from other factory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

```
IFactory.query(
    function (response) {
        $scope.type_content = response;
        $scope.showMenu = true;
    },
    function (response) {
        $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
    }
); 

$scope.saving = {
    firstname: "how",
    lastname: "are you",
    type_num: "1",
    usertype: []
};   
UserFactory.save($scope.saving);
```

I am able to retrieve data from IFactory using query and saving the response in type_content. Now what I want to do is data which is in type_content I want to save it usertype as it is, because schema for used for type_content and usertype is same.
Please note that Data coming from IFactory has used embedded schema ( use of arrays).

Comment: Is `Ifactory` a `ngResource` object?

Comment: Yes we are using ngResource

.factory('IFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource, baseURL) {

        return $resource(baseURL + "t1/:id", null, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });

}])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Ifactory.query` returns a `$resource` object, the code can use its `$promise` property for chaining.

```
IFactory.query().$promise.then(
    function onSuccess(typeContent) {
        $scope.type_content = typeContent;
        $scope.showMenu = true;
        //return typeContent for chaining
        return typeContent;
}).catch(
    function (errorResponse) {
        $scope.message = "Error: " + errorResponse.status + " " + errorResponse.statusText;
        //throw to chain errorResponse
        throw errorResponse;
}).then(
    function onSuccess2(typeContent) {
        $scope.saving = {
            firstname: "how",
            lastname: "are you",
            type_num: "1",
            usertype: typeContent
        };   
        UserFactory.save($scope.saving);
});
```

By **returning** and **chaining**, the `$q` service waits before invoking the `onSuccess2` function which executes the `UserFactory.save` function. If there is an error, the `$q` service will skip the `onSucess2` function.